# Core data crashes the app

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, core-data

I am building a game and I am using core data to save the current level of it. 
Everything seemed to work fine, but now my app crashes when it tries to obtain the current level from the core data. Here is my core data stack:

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("GameState", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("GameName.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

}

and here is my method for obtaining the current level:

```
    func fetchTheCurrentLevel() {

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"CurrentLevel")
    var error: NSError?
    var fetchedResults =
    managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
        error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]



    if let results = fetchedResults {
        if count(results) > 0 {
            let currentLevel = results[results.count - 1]
            if let num = currentLevel.valueForKey("currentLevel") as? NSNumber {
                let level = num.shortValue
                levelToShow = level
            } else {
                levelToShow = 1
            }
        } else {
            println("no objects found")
            levelToShow = 1
        }
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

and finally, this the error I am getting: CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F60E246B-19C3-4EA5-B1E7-100EAC9DCC92/Documents/GameName.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" and it says that the reason = The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Have you made any recent changes to your model?

Comment: I did, but I just added more atributtes..

Comment: Doesn't matter, you need to either migrate your model or delete the app and reinstall if you are still in beta.